# Is there a way for a python script to know what type of file it is?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

So I have a Python script which I make into an `exe` with py2exe and I want it to do certain tasks only when the `exe` version is running.  Is there a way to write the code so I don't have to manually save a separate version before I create the `exe`?

I'm picturing something like this:

```
if self.filename[-4:] == ".exe":
    do this code
```

So it would somehow be able to find its own file name. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import sys
...
if sys.argv[0].endswith('.exe'):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ".exe" in self.fileName:
    print "it's an exe file!"
```

Given that self.filename = "someprogram.exe"

Comment: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The py2exe docs give a way to do this:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/HowToDetermineIfRunningFromExe

```
import imp, os, sys

def main_is_frozen():
    return (hasattr(sys, "frozen") or # new py2exe
            hasattr(sys, "importers") # old py2exe
            or imp.is_frozen("__main__")) # tools/freeze
```